# How to scale a flexible bar chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 am am trying to scale this bar chart (so that the longest bar is longer and the shortest bar is shorter)

This is my code, which allows my chart to be flexible when more data is added.

```
 <svg width="800" height="600"><g class="group"></g>
 </svg>

 var w = 500;
 var h = 130;
 var barPadding = 2;

 var data = [
 {"name": "The Kings speech", "time": 118},
 {"name": "Slumdog Millionaire", "time": 120},
 {"name": "Shakespeare in Love", "time": 122},
 {"name": "Chariots of Fire", "time": 123},
 ]

 d3.select('svg g.group')
.selectAll('rect')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
.attr('x', function(d, i) {return i * (w / data.length)})
.attr('y', function(d) {return h - d['time'];})
.attr('width', w / data.length - barPadding)
.attr('height', function(d) {return d['time'];})
```

I have tried using a scale function, like this, but it does not work

```
 var Scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([100, 150]).range([0, 50]);

.attr('x', function(d, i) {return i * (w / data.length)})
.attr('y', function(d) {return h - Scale(d['time'];})
.attr('width', w / data.length - barPadding)
.attr('height', function(d) {return Scale(d['time'];)}
```

Is this a good approach? What else can I try? Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the scale doesn't work?

Comment: I have made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hp3q498s/ I mean that the original code works, but when I add the scale, my chart stops creating any bars and I can't figure out why. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error in your fiddle...

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it? Sorry, I'm a beginner

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/hp3q498s/1/

Comment: Ah, thats what syntax means! Thank you so much, that works wonderfully and I can see where I went wrong. Thanks again.